# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in nam ubuntu 14.04

Tags: segmentation-fault

when i use NS2  through terminal i keep getting a segment fault (core dumped) message.

```
g_0zek@g-0zeK-pc:~$ ns lab1.tcl
g_0zek@g-0zeK-pc:~$ nam lab1.nam
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

despite that `xgraph` works ok

the code in the `tcl` seems ok as it was given from university and one friend of mine runs it fine. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Do not install via terminal.

Download ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/nsnam/

Install the following dependicies

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev gcc-4.4 g++-4.4 build-essential autoconf automake perl xgraph libxt-dev libx11-dev libxmu-dev.
```

Extract `ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz`

open `ns-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/linkstate/ls.h` file.

go to line number 137.

change

```
"void eraseAll() {erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end());}"
```

to

```
"void eraseAll() { this->erase(baseMap::begin(), baseMap::end()); }"
```

then goto ns-allinone-2.35 directory

```
cd home/isysway/ns-allinone-2.35/
./install
```

it takes some time

come to home directory

```
isysway@isysway:~$ sudo gedit .bashrc
```

a text file will open

go to end of the file

add the following line

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/isysway/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/isysway/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/isysway/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/isysway/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14/lib:/home/isysway/ns-allinone-2.35/lib
TCL_LIBRARY=$TCL_LIBRARY:/home/isysway/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library
export PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export TCL_LIBRARY
```

note:my user name is "isysway" you replace it with yours

```
isysway@isysway:~$source .bashrc
```

then

```
isysway@isysway:~$ns

%
```

if the modulo symbol comes you did it.

Comment: Thanks @Amal, worked for me without any problem! (Ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed NS correctly. How ? east download one TCl file which does not run nam. If you do not know nam is just for depicting the algorithm graphically. After download and run TCL file ( As I said download nam free or at least your self disable that line or make them as comment on your TCL file .

There is some problems on running nam on 14.04 . You should download nam from [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns2-version-2-34-is-too-old-wpan-802-15-4-a-4175499373/page2.html) and copy  the extracted file in to your /usr/local/bin . But I just test that for ubuntu 32 bit 14.04
.

By the way if you are new to NS2. I should tell you it not necessary to follow erlang NS2 method. If you are enough not in horry I recommend you to look at here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/ns2-version-2-34-is-too-old-wpan-802-15-4-a-4175499373/

Answer (score 0):

I think there must be a bug in the Ubuntu 14.04 package. Probably the best thing to do is install from source until a package maintainer fixes the problem. I have gone ahead [reported the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nam/+bug/1376970).