# NAM installation problem in NS2, Segmentation Fault

Tags: segmentation-fault

I am having trouble running the network animator on Ubuntu14.04.  It
gives me this error `segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I am using NAM version
1.15 and ns2-2.34.

Comment: Looks like an identical question with no answer yet, http://askubuntu.com/questions/467901/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-ns2-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: yep, they are bugs.

Comment: looks like my answer on the Clayton's link comment, that problem happen for me before

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same error... The following will help u to get the exact result... Try to install ns2 with the procedure given in the link
 "[Segmentation fault (core dumped) in nam ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467901/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-ns2-ubuntu-14-04)".
 If you have installed ns2 successfully and still getting "Segmentation fault", then do the following step

**copy the 'nam' file from your '/home/[username]/ns-allinone-2.35/nam-1.15' folder and paste it into '/usr/local/bin' folder**
now surely it will work... restart your terminal and execute your tcl script