# nam error : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: 14.04, segmentation-fault, ns2

I'm trying to use ns2 in ubuntu 14.04 (32 bit). But I'm having a great trouble using nam

I can use ns2 command easily

```
$ ns example.tcl
```

But the nam is not working properly. On executing the below command

```
$ nam example.nam
```

I'm getting error

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I followed all the steps in below article. But still not working properly

[Segmentation fault (core dumped) in nam ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467901/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-in-ns2-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: You could start with `/bin/ls -l example.{tcl,nam}`, `man ns2`, `man nam`, `strace $(type -p nam) example.nam`, `man strace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a ns2 installed manually in your system just go in the directory of ns2 for example `ns2-allinone-2.35/ns-2.35/` then try to simulate your simulation in here and be sure that you use `./ns ./simulationfile.tcl` instead of `ns simulationfile.tcl`.